# How to resolve IIS 500.19 with Error Code 0x8007000d to run .net core 2.2

Tags: .net-core

I am not able host the asp.net core 2.2 web api on windows server 2019 iis 10.
I get HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. I created self contained deployment and even install url rewrite also. But still i am not able to resolve this error. Please help me resolve this issue

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error
Config File    \?\F:\Publish\Renault\web.config
Requested URL      http://localhost:9095/
Physical Path
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

Comment: Did you install dotnet core hosting bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the resolution. After installing ASP.net core 3.1.7 hosting model my problem got resolved.
https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/21a5322f-cf9c-40e0-af41-4cdf14b3fb17/ff1390906525099bcd6b322279e09938/dotnet-hosting-3.1.7-win.exe